# select new derived class from EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In c# Entity Framework 4 or 5

Entity Class #1

```
public class ClassOne
{
   public string FirstName { get;set; }
}

public class ClassTwo : ClassOne
{
    public string LastName get;set; }
}
```

for an IQueryable:

```
return from e in Context.pClassOneList from r in SomeOtherList select new ClassTwo
{

    // right here how do I get all the fields assigned without having to do it manually? ie:
    FirstName = e.FirstName,



    LastName = r.SomeOtherVar // works perfectly, but the whole of ClassOne is not assigned unless I do it manually.
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. (What is your question?)

Comment: Create a copy constructor. You can save on boilerplate with something like AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the only way to automatically bind the properties of the base class in an expression would be to dynamically generate the select expression on the fly. This would be a fair amount of work and would slow down your code. I don't think this is the way to go. However, perhaps rather than extending the base class you can simply encapsulate it—you can embed the result in another object, like this:

```
public class ResultType 
{
    public ClassOne ClassOne { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherVar { get; set; }
}

return  
    from e in Context.pClassOneList 
    from r in SomeOtherList 
    select new ResultType
    {
        ClassOne = e,
        SomeOtherVar = r.SomeOtherVar
    };
```

Comment: I would like to have e as the full loaded class of (ClassOne) and be able to assign properties of r (ClassTwo) onto the existing ClassOne. Is that better? haha

Comment: @user2638032 You still wouldn't be able to do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're basically grabbing two different lists and then instantiating a new object using an object initializer so of course you're going to have to do it manually.

You could create a constructor in ClassTwo that takes a ClassOne and hydrates the inherited properties of ClassTwo or even approach it with an adapter pattern.

SomeOtherList might have to be handled "manually" depending on what it contains. But, please mind your SOLID principles when you start getting creative with your constructors.